# Edge centrality measures in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

Igraph R package has the implemented edge betweenness centrality. I am aware that there are other edge centrality measures studied in the literature. Are there packages that include some other edge centrality measures for instance k-path edge centrality measure ? Can we compute an edge centrality index using a line graph of a graph under question ?

Answer (score 0):

The `CINNA` package [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CINNA/index.html) supports all kinds of centrality measures, including also k-path edge centrality, I believe.

You can view the measures with:

```
library("igraph")
library("CINNA")

g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 0.2)
proper_centralities(g)
#[1] "subgraph centrality scores"                      
#[2] "Topological Coefficient"                         
#[3] "Average Distance"                                
#[4] "Barycenter Centrality"                           
#[5] "BottleNeck Centrality"                           
#[6] "Centroid value"                                  
#[7] "Closeness Centrality (Freeman)"                  
# ...                       
#[16] "K-core Decomposition"                            
#[17] "Geodesic K-Path Centrality"                      
#[18] "Katz Centrality (Katz Status Index)"             
# ...                 
#[41] "Stress Centrality"                               
#[42] "Load Centrality"                                 
#[43] "Flow Betweenness Centrality"                     
#[44] "Information Centrality"                          
#[45] "Dangalchev Closeness Centrality"                 
#[46] "Group Centrality"                                
#[47] "Harmonic Centrality"                             
#[48] "Local Bridging Centrality"                       
#[49] "Wiener Index Centrality"
```

As you can see, there are plenty to choose from. The `calculate_centralities` function can the calculate the measures for a given graph.

Comment: Unfortunately, the CINNA package includes only vertex centralities, for instance Geodesic K-Path Centrality.

Comment: @PiotrWilczek Arh! I was too quick.

Comment: The only edge centrality I know by heart is `edge_betweenness` in igraph.